# How do I make a window immediately close after pressing the button that's inside that window

Tags: python, tkinter

It's very hard to explain in words so I'll go by it through sequential pictures

Here's how it looks like at first: [pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmV6o.png)

Here's my code:

```
`import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox


class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x400")
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.root, width=11, text="btn1", font=('Satoshi', 15),command=self.add).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def add(self):
        extra = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        extra.geometry("500x200")

        button = tk.Button(extra, text="btn1", font=('Satoshi', 15), command=self.added).pack()


    def added(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("test", "button pressed succesfully!")
`
```

[After pressing the 1st button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4O7l.png)

That appears right, so then I'll press the second button:

[It would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPnCP.png)

I want it to look like this:

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iutyP.png)

So after I press the button 2 window, it will then close and the message box would appear that I have successfully pressed the button.

Sorry I can't really explain it well with words. But that's the gist of my problem. I want to make it so that when I press button 2, it's window will close and the message box would appear.

Still new to tkinter. PS: I don't want to close the entire program. I do know how to use the destroy command however, that's not the case for this.

Comment: Try adding `extra.destroy()` in the button press function, `added(self):` in your case. With `destroy()` you can close any tkinter window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use destroy() in extra window based on you msgbox response..

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox


class Test(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x400")
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.root, width=11, text="btn1", font=('Satoshi', 15),command=self.add).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def add(self):
        self.extra = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.extra.geometry("500x200")

        button = tk.Button(self.extra, text="btn1", font=('Satoshi', 15), command=self.added).pack()


    def added(self):
        msg_result = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("test", "button pressed succesfully!")
        if msg_result == 'ok':
            self.extra.destroy()


app = Test()
app.mainloop()
```